# access property set in service setup() in hook

Tags: feathersjs

Setting a property in service setup(). Need to access that property in the service's hooks.

```
setup(app) {
    this.app = app;
    this.meta = { mod: 'verify' };
}
```

How to service property 'meta', in the service hook?

Tried
context.service
context.meta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property was available in context.service, and accessed it as below

```
const meta = context.service.meta;
```

Not sure if there is any other way to access it.